# R Cran package with Rcpp builds on every system but Solaris

Tags: r, solaris, rcpp

I am working on an R library submitted to CRAN, where it compiles on all the platforms but Solaris.
Thanks to [The R-hub builder](https://builder.r-hub.io/) website, I was able to get two different types of errors on that system (otherwise I have no access to any Solaris machine).

However, I have no idea about the error that I get. Moreover, the behaviour with two compilers is quite different:

1. Using the option: "Oracle Solaris 10, x86, 32 bit, R-release", my code compiles but it crashes at runtime with a "segfault".
2. Using the option: "Oracle Solaris 10, x86, 32 bit, R-release, Oracle Developer Studio 12.6", the code does not even compile, getting a strange error:

> "rcpp_module.cpp", line 340: Error: The name function is ambiguous, void Rcpp::function<RESULT_TYPE>(const char*, RESULT_TYPE(*)(), const char*) and std::function<_Signature>.

Since the package compiles (with zero warnings) and executes on Windows, Ubuntu, CentOs, Mac OS X, but I have no clue about what should I look for as possible errors.

Did anyone else have the same problems? Do you have any hints?

Thanks for any support.

**UPDATED ON 30.04.2021**: I have worked out a minimal example reproducing the error for on R-hub builder for the system *Oracle Solaris 10, x86, 32 bit, R-release, Oracle Developer Studio 12.6*. The results are available [here](https://artifacts.r-hub.io/SpatialKWD_0.3.2.tar.gz-38a2fc86887612c2ac0e50129d16c8de/).

In the rcpp_module.cpp file we have:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

#include "KWD_Histogram2D.h"

Rcpp::List compareAll(Rcpp::NumericMatrix Coordinates,  // This is line 49
    Rcpp::NumericMatrix Weights, int L = 3,
    bool recode = true, const std::string& method = "approx",
    const std::string& algorithm = "colgen",
    const std::string& model = "mincostflow",
    const std::string& verbosity = "silent",
    double timelimit = 14400, double opt_tolerance = 1e-06,
    bool unbalanced = false, double unbal_cost = 1e+09,
    bool convex = true) {

    Rcpp::List sol;

    return sol;
}

RCPP_MODULE(SKWD) {
    using namespace Rcpp;

    function("compareAll", &compareAll,
        List::create(_["Coordinates"], _["Weights"], _["L"] = 3,
            _["recode"] = true, _["method"] = "approx",
            _["algorithm"] = "colgen", _["model"] = "mincostflow",
            _["verbosity"] = "silent", _["timelimit"] = 14400,
            _["opt_tolerance"] = 1e-06, _["unbalanced"] = false,
            _["unbal_cost"] = 1e+09, _["convex"] = true),
        "compare all histograms using the given search options");
}
```

The included file KWD_Histogram2D.h is basically empty.
The error the R-hub outputs is as follows:

```
"rcpp_module.cpp", line 49: Error: The name function is ambiguous, void Rcpp::function<RESULT_TYPE>(const char*, RESULT_TYPE(*)(), const char*) and std::function<_Signature>.
1 Error(s) detected.
```

**UPDATED ON 02.05.2021**: The previous error vanishes after re-running the command `Rcpp::compileAttributes()` which rewrite the files `RcppExports.cpp` and `RcppExports.R`. However, even the basic Rcpp tutorial example with the *Student* class does not work on Solaris with *Oracle Developer Studio 12.6*. Now the error is similar to the following one:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for â€˜RcppStudentâ€™ in .doLoadActions(where, attach): error in load action .__A__.1 for package RcppStudent: loadModule(module = "RcppStudentEx", what = TRUE, env = ns, loadNow = TRUE): Unable to load module "RcppStudentEx": negative length vectors are not allowed Error: loading failed Execution halted
```

I have just reported this issue at [rcpp-modules-student](https://github.com/r-pkg-examples/rcpp-modules-student/issues/2).

**UPDATED ON 03.05.2021**: My C++ code compiles and runs correctly under Solaris 11 (via VirtualoBox) using gcc-5.5 installed via [OpenCSW](https://www.opencsw.org/). Hence, the bug lies somewhere in between the Rcpp wrapper I wrote, and the R system running under Solaris.

**UPDATED ON 07.05.2021**: I have answered to my own question below.

Comment: Different compilers have different levels of pickyness. If it fails on Solaris, there could be an issue.  But as you provide no [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  or link to the repo we cannot say much more.

Comment: You're right @DirkEddelbuettel, I hoped that my error was "common". I will try to work out a mcve. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know why you refuse to link to your Github repo

Comment: @HongOoi sorry, the link to GitHub is [Spatial-Kwd](https://github.com/eurostat/Spatial-KWD/). Since Dirk aked for a mcve, I did my best to isolate the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to reproduce the issue that was happening on the CRAN automated build system was to install locally a Solaris 10 in VirtualBox using the image available at https://files.r-hub.io/solaris/ and updating the version of R following the instructions described in the [solarischeck](https://github.com/r-hub/solarischeck/tree/master/packer) GitHub repository.

In the end, the error was in my code, since a *dangerous* logical expression between floating-point numbers was causing an infinite recursive call, and hence, there was an overflow of the C stack.

The issue was raised by Solaris by pure chance.

Comment: is it possible to reproduce the code that caused this here or link to the fixing commit?

Comment: The error was at line 383 of the file [KWD_Histogram2D](https://github.com/eurostat/Spatial-KWD/blob/main/include/KWD_Histogram2D.h), combined with the loop starting at 0 (instead of 1) at line 381. Starting at 0, when comparing an element with itself the comparison at line 383 was always true. The whole algorithm for computing the convex hull could be improved, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

in the code on [Github](https://github.com/eurostat/Spatial-KWD/blob/main/wrappers/R/src/rcpp_module.cpp) on line 335-340

```
  .method("num_arcs", &KWD::Solver::num_arcs,
          "get the number of arcs in the Network model")

  .method("num_nodes", &KWD::Solver::num_nodes,
          "get the number of arcs in the Network model")
```

Should not be the second nodes?

```
 .method("num_nodes", &KWD::Solver::num_nodes,
         "get the number of nodes in the Network model")
```

Comment: Thanks, fixed in my local branch. It will be update online tomorrow.

Comment: By the way, that is only a documentation error, since the fourth string is used to document the method in the R help file, and it is not related at all to the error of my question.

Comment: Correct comment. I do not understand why four people upvoted this. It may be well intentioned but it has *zero* to do with your question or problem.